# How to authenticate update site in eclipse-rcp

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, equinox, p2

How can I authenticate update site url when accessed through web or rcp application(version 3.x and 4.x).

Referred URL: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093851/ 
and https://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t106640.html

In 1st url question it is mentioned use of LoginDialog (org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.UserValidationDialog) but I am not aware how to use it in code.

I also followed steps mentioned in 2nd url but unable to get any dialog.

Please find below image links with 4 steps mentioned with numbers and I want authentication dialog between steps 3 and 4

[Image with steps 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5gwE.png)

[Image with step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HG0d.png)

[Image with step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTGYt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From referred URL https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1093851/

> p2 uses the OSGi Services mechanism to find services. You'll want to provide an implementation of the org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.UIServices;

Try to add "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui" with its dependencies to your RCP, this bundle registers the `public class ValidationDialogServiceUI extends UIServices` that uses `org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.dialogs.UserValidationDialog`